# Wake-up pc AND get to the Desktop

Tags: remote-desktop

I have a problem, please help me solve it.

I have a remote pc, i can set it up from Bios to wake up at a specific time (early morning).
The problem is there is a user list and i need to click on a specific user to reach the desktop. I need to do this to start a remote access software (teamviewer). All the programs provided by google did not help me solve this problem - aka reach the desktop. So if it just opens my pc but fails to get me to desktop it's useless.

Any idea how i could do that?

Thanks a lot!
Edit: it's Win 7, forgot to say it.

Comment: If you have just one local useraccount with no password there is no login screen. Remove all other accounts. Make sure it is a local account without a password.

Comment: can't remove other accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Press Windows key + R to open the Run window. In the text field type `regedit` and press Enter.

Now expand the following:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE \ SOFTWARE \ Microsoft \ Windows NT \ CurrentVersion`

Now Select `WinLogon` folder, in you should see:

`DefaultUserName` - this should be set to your account you can right click and select modify to change

Now Right click in an empty space and select New --> String Value set the Name as `DefaultPassword` (all one word) and the value to your password.

Finally make sure the `AutoAdminLogon` is set to 1

Now it should log you in automatically when you start up your machine.